# cronR cronjob working on ubuntu/local system but not in shinyapp.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Cron Job is not working after deployment on shinyapp.io

We are trying to schedule some jobs in our shinyapp through cronR, it is working on local system but no as soon as when we are deploying it on shinyapp.io server it is showing a below error.

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).


Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Adding cronjob:
---------------

# cronR job
# id:   temp_data_fetch
# tags: lab, xyz
# desc: temp Data Loading
0-59 * * * * /opt/R/3.5.3/lib/R/bin/Rscript '/srv/connect/apps/Temp/ETL.R'  >> '/srv/connect/apps/Temp/ETL.log' 2>&1
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : error in running command
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

        #Cron Script
        if(!(file.exists("/srv/connect/apps/Temp/scripts_scheduled.rds"))){
            cmd <- cronR::cron_rscript(rscript = '/srv/connect/apps/Temp/ETL.R')
            cronR::cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'minutely', id = 'temp_data_fetch',description = 'temp Data Loading',tags = c('lab', 'xyz'))
            TEXT<-"temp_data_fetch"
            saveRDS(TEXT,"/srv/connect/apps/Temp/scripts_scheduled.rds")
        }

        #ETL.R 

        trigger_time <- readRDS(file = "/srv/connect/apps/Temp/trigger_time.rds")
        trigger_time <- c(trigger_time,paste(Sys.time()))
        saveRDS(trigger_time,file = "/srv/connect/apps/Temp/trigger_time.rds")
```